# Django Test Client client.post() sends GET request in my Testcase

Tags: python, django, testing, post, client

How can I submit a POST request with Django test Client? I just want to test the login function of my application. It's strange that I put 
**`response = self.client.post(reverse('rbac:login'), data=data)`** in my testcase, and I want to validate it so I print **`response.status_code`**.Actually it should return 302 coz it should turn to another page. but it return 200. This situation happens when I use "**`python manage.py test testmodel`**" to test. However, if I use "**`python manage.py shell`**" to make an InteractiveConsole and write exactly the same code, it return 302 at last.

I have nearly tried all the methods provided from stack overflow, e.g. change the url, offer the content-type when I post....but these are meaningless.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment,teardown_test_environment
from django.test import Client
from django.urls import reverse
import django
from rbac.models import RbacUser, RbacRole
from system_module.models import Redeploy
from urllib import urlencode
class CreateUser(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_create_user(self):
        data = {"Username": "admin_xy", "Password": "aaa"}

        response = self.client.post(reverse('rbac:login'), data=data)
        print response
```

and it shows me 200.....
However, in interactive console:

```
>>> response = client.post(reverse('rbac:login'), data=data)
>>> print response.status_code                                                                                                                 
302
```

it shows the right result.
I want to know how to cope with this annoying problem. Thx

I expect when I use test file to test my test case, it works fine....like show 302 code.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the POST or GET request by using Client, first you need to create the user make the user active and give necessary permissions and login through client and then send the post request.

Ex: `self.client.login(username='username', 'password'='password)`

Comment: He's testing login, so you do *not* want the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It's been long time that this question is here, I hope you found the answer, but for other people I'll suggest to add this to this code to be redirected:

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('rbac:login'), data=data, follow=True)
```

The `follow=True` will follow the redirect .